# sagemaker.tensorflow.serving predict failed with 502 error

Tags: python, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

I deployed a tensorflow saved_model on using the following code:

```
`model_path = 's3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/model/model.tar.gz'
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model
model = Model(model_data=model_path, role=role)
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c5.xlarge')`
```

the model takes images of dimensions `1,48,48,1`

Immediately after, when I try to make a prediction using the following code:

```
`predictor.predict(preprocessed_faces_emo.tolist())`
```

I get the following error, and I know understand what the problem is. I am using this code from within sagemaker with Python version 3.7 and Tensorflow version 1.14.0:

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-4dc04dc0679c> in <module>()
----> 1 predictor.predict(preprocessed_faces_emo.tolist())~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args)
    105 
    106         request_args = self._create_request_args(data, initial_args)
--> 107         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    108         return self._handle_response(response)
    109 ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    355                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    356             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 357             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    358 
    359         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    659             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    660             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 661             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    662         else:
    663             return parsed_responseModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (502) from model with message "<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
". See https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-2020-01-13-13-43-12-354 in account 970351559819 for more information.`
```

Comment: Did you look at the log in Cloudwatch?

Comment: Yeah. the error that I mentioned is from Cloudwatch.

Comment: @AhsanMemon did u solve this issue?

Comment: Instead of `predictor.predict(preprocessed_faces_emo.tolist())` which was for an individual sample, you can try `predictor.predict([preprocessed_faces_emo.tolist()])` because the endpoint expects a batch. You can refer to [this comment](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/1485#issuecomment-630054895) and also you can take a look at the entire issue for more info. Thanks!